# Calling other functions from a threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to generate content for my blog with gpt, works fine with a single thread but takes over 2 minutes to generate 1 article. While I try to MultiThread or MultiProcess it, it just won't work.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried putting it all under one function and nesting functions within the function and everything else a late beginner / early intermediate coder could think of.

I typed the below code in a hurry so pl ignore minor mistakes, but this should give you an idea. qform forms questions from a list of topics in a file and that is multithreaded, and the test prints suggest that is working fine. But qform in turn isn't calling gpt like it should 6 times, and the wppost definitely isn't being called after that.

```
def wppost(title,content):
 r=post(title,content)
 print(r)

def gpt(q):
 gr=openai.completion(prompt=q)

def qform():
 with open('file) as f:
  for line in f:
   q1='what is '+f
   q2='were is '+f
   q3....q6
   gptq=gpt(q=q1+...q6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 with open file as fm:
  with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
   for i in enumerate(fm):
    executor.submit(qform)
```

Comment: You can't write to a single file from multiple threads.  The outputs will be interspersed so as to make the file nonsense.  However, there's nothing here that will take two minutes.  Are you sending this to a web site?

Comment: I strongly suspect that there's relevant code missing here. What's shown is certainly not runnable

Comment: @TimRoberts yes this is not the exact code I run, gpt(q) takes in multiple keywords fetched from a file at the same time and runs it 6 times with different question formats, and puts them all together and writes to a file as an article, which then later gets fetched by a requests.post function to post into wordpress api. The file is super jumbled and is nonsense. I am looking for a way to have it written in order. I've tried calling the openai function from within one variable, isn't working either.

Comment: You can't do computing in parallel if the output needs to be serial.  Perhaps the best you can do is have each thread write to a different file, then when all threads are finished. combine them.